# Could not find property 'release' on project ':app' Error

Tags: android

I am implementing material design in my application.
I am getting error "Error:(2, 0) Could not find property 'release' on project ':app'." at time of building my gradle

here is my gradle code:

```
      apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
      name=release
      storeFile=null
      storePassword=null
      keyAlias=null
      keyPassword=null
      storeType=null

      android {
         compileSdkVersion 21
         buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

      defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.rey.material.demo"
         minSdkVersion 9
         targetSdkVersion 21
         versionCode 5
         versionName "0.0.5"
      }

      signingConfigs {
        release {
           storeFile file(MATERIAL_KEYSTORE_FILE)
           storePassword MATERIAL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
           keyAlias MATERIAL_KEYSTORE_ALIAS
           keyPassword MATERIAL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
        }
      }

      buildTypes {
        release{
           minifyEnabled true
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
     }
  }

     dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
       compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
       compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
       compile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
       compile project(':lib')
     }
```

please help me,
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't need below code

```
      name=release
      storeFile=null
      storePassword=null
      keyAlias=null
      keyPassword=null
      storeType=null
```

remove these lines and check again!
it should look like this now

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

      android {
         compileSdkVersion 21
         buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

      defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.rey.material.demo"
         minSdkVersion 9
         targetSdkVersion 21
         versionCode 5
         versionName "0.0.5"
      }

      signingConfigs {
        release {
           storeFile file('MATERIAL_KEYSTORE_FILE_Path')
           storePassword 'password'
           keyAlias 'keyAliasName'
           keyPassword 'MATERIAL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD'
        }
      }

      buildTypes {
        release{
           minifyEnabled true
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
     }
  }

     dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
       compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
       compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
       compile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
       compile project(':lib')
     }
```

Comment: but,if i remove it, i got error like: Error:(17, 0) Could not find property 'MATERIAL_KEYSTORE_FILE' on SigningConfig_Decorated{name=release, storeFile=null, storePassword=null, keyAlias=null, keyPassword=null, storeType=null}.

Comment: check edited answer, and sync the build.gradle file.

Comment: welcome, if it helped pls upvote and accept the answer!!

Comment: @Riya if this answer helped you, please accept this answer.